# Can we return the same model data from one controller method to two jsp pages?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, model

Is it possible to return the same model data from one controller method to two jsp pages.

```
Please find below jsp pages :

jsp 1: Welcome.jsp

Jsp 2 : Hello.jsp
```

Controller :

```
@SuppressWarnings("boxing")
    @Override
    public ModelAndView Welcome(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
            final ProductModel component){

    model.put("product", product1);
    return new ModelAndView(this.getView(),model);

        }
```

Comment: How would you visit more than one jsp from a single controller? Not sure I understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Plog i need same data to be printed in both jsp pages with different view so i want it..

Comment: For one request (controller) you receive one response with one page.